# Cannot select JSON elements

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation, weather-api

I'm brand new to web dev but I'm trying to create a Weather app using the `openweatherapp` API: https://openweathermap.org/current#geo . The JSON object is below:

```
{"coord":{"lon":5.38,"lat":34.72},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.903,"pressure":1000.23,"humidity":65,"temp_min":280.903,"temp_max":280.903,"sea_level":1031.37,"grnd_level":1000.23},"wind":{"speed":8.5,"deg":317},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1486603649,"sys":{"message":0.3449,"country":"DZ","sunrise":1486621797,"sunset":1486660553},"id":2475612,"name":"Tolga","cod":200}
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// findind my latitude and longitude 
if(navigator.geolocation){

 function success(position){
 var lat = position.coords.latitude.toString();
 var long = position.coords.longitude.toString();
 $("p").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + long); 

 // using the API to get the weather from those lat and long values
 $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat  + "&lon=" + long+"&appid=6a5aa3b59ebd571086cbd82be484ec8b", function(a){
    temp = a[0].main.temp.toString();
    hum = a[0].main.humidity.toString();
    press= a[0].main.pressure.toString();
    name = a[0].name;
    $("h1").html(temp);
 });
};


 };

function failure(){
  $("p").html("Not working");
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,failure);


});
```

The lat and long part is running fine but not the API for the weather.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my codepen to make it simpler : https://codepen.io/tadm123/pen/OWojPx

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me. Make sure that your browser has permission to know your location and that the computer has GPS. This probably will not work on a desktop.

Try manually setting the lat and long values and it should work.